# What is error in partition code?

Tags: c, quicksort, partitioning

Below code is working for Array{ 4 5 3 7 2 }, but not working for other test case given on HackerRank Site. What is error in my code?
Am I doing any wrong while merging the two array a1[] and a2[] into the ar[] ?

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
void partition(int ar_size, int *  ar) {
    int a1[100], a2[100];
    int p = ar[0];
    int i=0, j=0 , k=0;
    for(i=0; i<ar_size; i++){
        if(ar[i] < p)
         {
            a1[j] = ar[i];
            j++;
        }      
        else if(ar[i] >= p){
            a2[k] = ar[i];
            k++;
        }            
    }

    i=0, j=0 , k=0;

    while(a1[i]){
        ar[i] = a1[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    while(a2[k]){
        ar[i] = a2[k];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<ar_size; i++){
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);          
    }

}
int main(void) {

   int _ar_size;
scanf("%d", &_ar_size);
int _ar[_ar_size], _ar_i;
for(_ar_i = 0; _ar_i < _ar_size; _ar_i++) { 
   scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]); 
}

partition(_ar_size, _ar);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it with different testcases yourself?

Comment: I tried with many case. It gives different and awkward result . Its giving right answer for Array{ 4 5 3 7 2 }.

Comment: the number of elements `1≤n≤1000`

Comment: `int a1[100], a2[100];` are not initialized.

Comment: while(a) what is a? a is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove i=0, j=0 , k=0; and what follows, and try the following

```
while(k--){
    ar[k+j] = a2[k];
}
while(j--){
    ar[j] = a1[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int _ar_size;
scanf("%d", &_ar_size);
int _ar[_ar_size], _ar_i;
```

You cannot initialize an array with unknown number , when you initialize an variable or an array.. you should know how much will need ( if you dont know the size you need just do initialize the array with a big number or use a linked list)
because the pc or whatever should know how much he will allocate in the memory.

Comment: There is no problem with main function. It is default code written in HackerRank's code editor.

Comment: what `ar1` and `ar2` contain ?
if they dont contain anything how you gave the value to another array ?

Comment: if you used `c90` you will get `error: ISO C90 forbids variable length array _ar` using `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -o s s.c` but `c99` works fine using `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -o s s.c`